# Accessing Bitbucket Git repository from different Windows domains

Tags: windows, git, dns, bitbucket

my development setup consists of "Visual Studio Code" as editor as well as Bitbucket as central code repository. However, VS Code runs within a different Windows domain than Bitbucket which doesn't seem to work properly. Whereas my user name is the same in both domains, my password differs. And it seems as if the Bitbucket credentials are passed to Bitbucket using the wrong, VS Code domain settings. Is it even possible to get such setup as mine to work?

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?  Is it Basic (username and password), NTLM, or GSSAPI (Kerberos)?